# Google sheet adding a layer on top of a vlookup to make it conditional on a yes/no and a date

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to put in a basic toggle into a Google sheet.

Here is my reference table, It gets imported from another Google document so it's updated all the time.

[image]

I also have another google sheet that goes back to this lookup reference. It fills in the data if the date is less than today's date and matches the Date and the Source columns as a key.

[image]

I'd like to add another part in the Google sheet that says Include Today and you can type in the word "Yes"

[image]

If you type in Yes, I would like the yellow section, that uses the lookup_ref reference table, to include today's date, and otherwise include only days before today. In the example here, today is October 14, so if we type in "Yes" into this field, we need to have a value other than 0 for V15.

Comment: You questions isn't clear. Please add a sample data with expected output

Comment: I rewrote the post. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you want to optionally include today's values in the formula. So you can conditionally add 1 day to today based on the value of "Include Today".

For example, if you add "Include Today" Yes/No value at cell "Z1", then you need to add `IF(Z1="yes",1,0)`. So your formula can be

```
=IFERROR(IF(O15 < today() + IF(Z1="yes",1,0), vlookup(A15,lookup_ref,4,false), 0),0)
```

Comment: awesome solution thank you